# Using Streamlit to chat with PDF document --> Segmentation fault: 11 renders Streamlit app unusable

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit, langchain

I'm new to LangChain & Streamlit.  When I run the below code, I keep getting an error once I run the Streamlit app -- "Segmentation fault: 11".
I am then unable to get the app to render.

Any idea on what this segmentation fault means?

I am using Python 3.10.

The Terminal output is as follows:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/<username>/Documents/GitHub/langchain-ade-private/demo1.py
2023-10-31 16:44:34.578 
  Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
  command:

    streamlit run /Users/<username>/Documents/GitHub/langchain-ade-private/demo1.py [ARGUMENTS]

$ streamlit run /Users/<username>/Documents/GitHub/langchain-ade-private/demo1.py

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: <Local URL>
  Network URL: <Network URL>

  For better performance, install the Watchdog module:

  $ xcode-select --install
  $ pip install watchdog
            
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is my source code:

```
# file name: demo1.py

# pip install
# !pip3 install langchain
# !pip3 install streamlit
# !pip3 install streamlit_chat
# !pip3 install pypdf
# !pip3 install openai
# !pip3 install chromadb
# !pip3 install tiktoken

# imports
import os
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
import streamlit as st

# set API keys and the models to use
API_KEY = "<OpenAI API Key>"

# add openai api key for use
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = API_KEY

loaders = PyPDFLoader('<PDF file>')

# create a vector representation of the loaded document
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loaders])

# setup streamlit app
st.title(' Query your PDF document ')
prompt = st.text_input("Enter your question to query your PDF documents")

# display the current response. No chat history is maintained
if prompt:
    response = index.query(llm=OpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.2), question = prompt, chain_type = 'stuff')

    # write the results from the LLM to the UI
    st.write("<b>" + prompt + "</b><br><i>" + response + "</i><hr>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```